# stm32f4xx spi miso and mosi remap

Tags: spi, stm32f4

I'm trying to make stm32f401ce's spi1 function work normally. as you can see from the [stm32f401ce's datasheet](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/st/stm32f4xx/dm00102166.pdf), 39page, it says PA6 used for SPI1_MISO
and PA7 used for SPI1_MOSI. As there is some problem with our hardware design,
I want to remap PA6 as SPI1_MOSI and remap PA7 as SPI1_MISO. Is it possible to
do that?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to remap the way you would like. PA6 is SPI1_MISO and can't be SPI1_MOSI. Same for PA7.
However SPI1_MISO is available on PB4 and SPI1_MOSI is available on PB5.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks.